# TARGET_OS_IPHONE failing at compile time

Tags: xcode, compiler-errors, compilation

I'm on Xcode 9.3 and strangely and trying to compile some conditional code for an iOS framework (which also has a macOS counterpart).

```
#if TARGET_OS_IPHONE || TARGET_OS_IOS
#warning "BUILDING IPHONE"
#else
#warning "BUILDING MAC"
#endif
```

Strangely I get the compile time warning for "BUILDING MAC" when it should be "BUILDING IPHONE". I've got another iOS project that I compile a framework for, and when comparing build-settings, I can't find a visible difference, yet the framework being built isn't compiling in my conditional code correctly. What am I doing wrong?

Here's a screenshot of my build settings for this framework.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly me. The header file where I was running this check was being called from another header file. Essentially, the 'calling' code had not yet imported the foundation headers. The following added above the global import fixed it:

```
#ifdef __OBJC__
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#endif
```